# Check postag patterns in python

Tags: python, nlp

I want to check if the given wordphrase is constituted with `NN`. If all are `NN` increase the `count` value.

For example if my wordphrase is `[('micro', 'NN'), ('blog', 'NN'), ('texts', 'NN')]` I should increase its count by one.

My current code is as follows.

```
w='micro blog texts'
postag = nltk.pos_tag(w.split())
            print(postag)
            count_inside = 0
            for ele in postag:
                if ele[1] == 'NN':
                    count_inside = count_inside + 1
            if count_inside == len(w.splits()):
                count = count + 1
```

Even though, it works correctly, I am interested in knowing if we can do this in python possibly in one line? If so, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generator expression in the `all` function for this. Here's a short demo.

```
count = 0 
postag = [('micro', 'NN'), ('walk', 'V'), ('texts', 'NN')]
count += all(u[1] == 'NN' for u in postag)
print(count)

postag = [('micro', 'NN'), ('blog', 'NN'), ('texts', 'NN')]
count += all(u[1] == 'NN' for u in postag)
print(count)
```

**output**

```
0
1
```

The `all` function and the related `any` function are quite efficient, and they short-circuit, which means they stop checking as soon as they have a definite result. So `all` stops the generator expression loop as soon as it detects a false result.